# Options for NM Electric Wire Laying on Attic Floor?

Tags: electrical, wiring, attic

I’ve got an unfinished attic with trusses and plywood floor. There’s electric wires running across the plywood floor without much slack to raise them up.

I don’t really want to pull up the floor, but even if I did, is notching the truss bottom chord allowed? To go under the plywood, would I have to raise it up a couple inches?

Are there solutions to run it on top of the floor?

Comment: Is your attic a crawl space? Does it have a permanent ladder or stairs to access it? Do you have plans to finish the space someday? You might be able to get away with something as simple as guard strips (e.g. pieces of wood attached next to the cables to protect from “physical damage”) depending on the answers to those questions if you’re simply going for code compliance.

Comment: @statueuphemism Attic is not a crawl space, has a ladder, and will not be finished.

Comment: So this site http://www.inspectionnews.net/home_inspection/electrical-systems-home-inspection-and-commercial-inspection/21599-wiring-attic-floor.html hurt my eyes reading through, but the gist of it was that you could run wires on top of the floor and still comply with code as long as you protected the wires with boards/strips. But I don't think anybody thought this was a wise thing to do.

Comment: @statueuphemism - So it's a pulldown ladder, which I can't get a straight answer if that's considered permanent or not. So I give up on that.

Comment: How many sets of wires are we talking about?

Comment: @whatsisname 4 sets of wires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just going for compliance without plans for finishing the space ever, then the cheapest solution is to attach guard strips next to the cable.

Excerpt from the National Electrical Code:

> ARTICLE 334 Nonmetallic-Sheathed Cable: Types NM, NMC, and NMS
>
> 334.23 In Accessible Attics. The installation of cable in accessible attics or roof spaces shall also comply with 320.23

> 320.23 In Accessible Attics. Type AC cables in accessible attics or roof spaces shall be installed as specified in 320.23(A) and (B).
>
> (A) Cables Run Across the Top of Floor Joists. Where run across the top of floor joists, or within 2.1 m (7 ft) of the floor or floor joists across the face of rafters or studding, the cable shall be protected by guard strips that are at least as high as the cable. Where this space is not accessible by permanent stairs or ladders, protection shall only be required within 1.8 m (6 ft) of the nearest edge of the scuttle hole or attic entrance.
>
> (B) Cable Installed Parallel to Framing Members.
> Where the cable is installed parallel to the sides of rafters, studs, or ceiling or floor joists, neither guard strips nor running boards shall be required, and the installation shall also comply with 300.4(D).

You would also need to make sure the cable is secured every 4.5 ft and within 12 inches of each outlet/junction box.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably going to have to either re-run the wiring to get it under the floor properly or raise up a new floor to give you a clear floor.

Notching/drilling guidelines:

[image: Notching/Drilling Guidelines]

From here:

[Notching/Drilling Link](https://buildingadvisor.com/notching-and-boring-joists/)

Comment: Would using junction boxes to insert additional wire into the circuits and running them along the overhead trusses be allowed?  Depending on how many wires are involved this might be easier and cheaper than redoing the floor to keep the wiring as is.

Comment: Not an expert, but are the rules for joists different than trusses (bottom chords)? Based on the limited research I've done, it seems like it's okay to make cuts in joists, but for trusses the response seems to generally be "no" but that you should contact the truss manufacturer or an engineer if you are going to do it anyways.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Overall that's not a bad solution depending but wanted to check on options for running along the floor first

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way (but not the cheapest) to get the space you need (and add strength the floor) is to pull the boards up, add some cross boards (1x3 or 1x4 boards would do) and then deck over the cross-boards. The cross-boards will give you more than enough clearance for the wires to remain where they are.

Comment: Costs some headroom in what is usually a very cramped space, though.